# Adding object on toolbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I add an object (in shape of rectangle for instance) to an  embedded in a stack panel tag.

I was able to show the objects (as rectangle) on it using  and  and then using the style in an xaml file using something like:

```
<stackpanel ...>
    <Expander Header="Controls" Content="{StaticResource FC}" IsExpanded="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

but need to insert object onto toolbox dynamically. any idea how this could be done through code?

Your help will be appreciated.
Amit

Answer (score 0):

Expander is a type of control which is considered to be a content type control. As such it only has one child ( the child I believe you are calling a 'toolbox') which according to your Xaml is the FC item. Do these steps to add your item to the FC item:

1. In Xaml give a name to the Expander so it can be accessed in code behind.
2. In codebehind get the expander via its name.
3. Access the property Content on the expander and cast it to the FC class.
4. Add the item you want into the FC's children or content (whatever it is you know and we don't so its my best guess).

Comment: FC is nothing but a style in xaml resourcedictionary. How can I cast to it?  Thank you!

Comment: If FC is not needed, then put new content into the Expander, such as a StackPanel, then your other needs within it.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you could give some help on this matter again. I'm assuming when you say it has only one child it doesn't mean only one control can be add up to it. Right? in this step what I need is some advice on what approach I should take. User of this program will need to enter a number and each number represents a control so by entering 123, controlA will be retrieved from the db and then it will be added to the toolbox (child of expander) or 456 then controlB and so on. However, I think all I need to make this happen is using UIElement ... how? not sure yet.

Comment: @amitkohan It depends on the object in question. Create a side project and place a panel into the code. Name that panel. Then from the codebehind try to add an item to its context, say a textbox to it in codebehind. That will show you what you need to do.